# How to horizontally center table inside div?

Tags: html, css

I have a `<table>` inside a `<div>`, with the styling below, the table is not being centered, why?

Shouldn't everything within the `<div>` be formatted like I styled in the CSS?

HTML

```
<div> 
  <table></table> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
div{ 
  border: 5px solid white; 
  border-radius: 5px; 
  margin: auto; 
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You are setting `margin: auto` on the div, so the div will be centred … however you have also left the div as `width: auto` so it will be as wide its container (once you account for margins, padding and borders).

You are setting `text-align: center` on the div, so the *inline* children of the div will be centred, but the table is not inline, so it isn't affected (some of the table cells contents might be, depending on inheritance).

If you want to centre the table then you have to centre the table itself.

```
table { margin: auto; }
```

Comment: Doesnt work.Does the table need to set a layout style ?

Comment: @lohiarahul — No.

Answer (score 11):

The `div` element is block-level, and a block-level element occupies the entire space of its parent container, so `margin: auto;` does not take any effects by default. And `text-align: center;` works only for the inline-level children, but `table` is not one of them.

You can set the `table` as inline table `display: inline-table;`, so all the inline children including the table will be centered by `text-align: center;` on the parent `div`.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}
table {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: inline-table;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello world</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You might want to use

```
table{
    margin: auto;
}
```

Here is a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/7mhpv51s/1/

Answer (score 0):

Just add margin to your table, as below. When you use `margin:auto` for `table` it `align` your `table` to `center` of `div`. Whereas when you use that on this `<div>` it will align that to center of `browser`.

```
table{
margin :auto;
}
```

And not to div,

```
div{
margin:auto /*No need over-here*/
}
```

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
div{
width: 80%; /* try different value for this */
margin: auto;
}
table{
margin: auto;
}
```